# How to show image after deleting it using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, smarty

I am generating images on the fly through PHP and saving them in temporary directory and showing it in **smarty** template. I want the images to be deleted automatically after displaying the images in smarty.

Is it possible that I can  delete the image before displaying them in smarty and show the images on page using buffer or something? 

My problem is that I get the image (in string format) from a webservice. Now I convert the string in PNG image and save it temporarily. I assign the image to a smarty variable and then template displays the image. Limitation for the base64 format is that I am working with 'Tikiwiki' cms. I created a module for that that is included in the CKeditor. Ckeditor in Tikiwik doesn't like the long base64 string in image source an corrupts all the page source (hope you get that).
Can I delete the image after showing it in smarty?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What happens if the user refreshes the page?

Comment: @CodeCaster image is created everytime the page is reloaded.

Comment: Its possible that the temp directory is full of images over time. We must clean it everytime.

Answer (score 3):

If you will only ever display the image once, you can send it to the browser as inline data in the HTML, instead of an URL.

You need to use the data pseudo url scheme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

The image data itself needs to be base 64 encoded. Like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode(file_get_contents('my_image.jpg')) ?>" />
```

As soon as you have read the image data into a string, you can delete it, or even better, don't write it to disk in the first place.

Comment: i cant use base64 encoding. I have limitations.

Comment: What limitation is that? base64_encode has been available since php 4. I'd understand if the problem was Internet Explorer < 8 support.

Comment: my CMS (Tikiwiki) doesn't allow me to use the base64 image format in the page module(that I am working with).

Comment: Do you mean you can't run PHP in the template? Just run the code in the controller, and pass it as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the "image file" data by display the image via a php file (eg. image.php?imageid=111)

Here an example for a jpeg image

```
header ('Content-length: ' .filesize($image_file));
header ('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile ($image_file);
unlink($image_file);
die();
```

Comment: And you can actually delete the file after the `readline()` call

Comment: @Cyril Tourist thats OK, but how to delete it after display?

Comment: @alex In this case, an actual file is read from the filesystem

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do it the way you're talking about, but you could do it like this.

Don't reference to the actual image, but to a proxy page instead, in which you put the following code:

```
$imageUrl = "/images/123.jpg"; // link to image
$imginfo = getimagesize($imageUrl); // get mime info

header("Content-type: " . $imginfo['mime']); // add Content-type header

readfile($imageUrl); // show image

unlink($imageUrl); // delete image
```

Comment: I need to delete it after dispaying it in the smarty template. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are generating the images in some sort of controller, which then puts the image URL's in your Smarty template. The template is then rendered and sent to the browser, after which the browser requests the generated images by the URL that is in the HTML page.

Now you want to delete the images after they have been sent to the browser, to preserve disk space:

> Its possible that the temp directory is full of images over time. We must clean it everytime.

Deleting resources after generating them, when they are needed again later, is not a decent solution, because generating images is a CPU-heavy process, so you should cache them as much as possible.

The only sensible thing to do here is simply get more disk space: having more users on a site that generates data, requires more space.

A somewhat less worse option would be to inline the images as suggested by [geon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10849952/266143), but you say you can't use base64 because of "limitations". What limitations are that? But then again will every request cause the images to be generated again.

If adding disk space is not an option, and the images really only need to be accessible for a short amount of time, you could create a `cron` job that deletes images that haven't been accessed for more than a given time.

Comment: your points are 100% right and I upvote for the sensible discussion. But my problem is that I get the image (in string format) from a webservice. Now I convert the string in PNG image and save it temporarily. I assign the image to a smarty variable and then template displays the image. Limitation for the base64 format is that I am working with 'Tikiwiki' cms. I created a module for that that is included in the CKeditor. Ckeditor in Tikiwik doesn't like the long base64 string in image source an corrupts all the page source (hope you get that). BTW, cron is the only option I believe.

Comment: @Arvind07 thanks for explaining. I understand the conditions you have to work with, and IMHO a cron job that deletes old image files is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you can never guarantee, that the image is really viewed (as long as you don't use the `data:` URI approach suggested by @geon). This is, you can't be sure, that the image is really viewed only by the client you created it for.

There is a kind of hacky workaround, though: Store the link between image and a random hash in the user's session and deliver (and delete) the image, if this hash appears in the URL:

```
if (isset($_GET['_imagelink'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION[$_GET['_imagelink']])) {
        $path = $_SESSION[$_GET['_imagelink']];
        if (is_file($path)) {
            readfile($path);
            unlink($path);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Smarty template in the previous request you just need to know the secret `_imagelink` variable and echo an URL with `?_imagelink={$_imagelink}`.

The disadvantage is, that you need to manually clean up the temp folder from time to time to auto-remove not-requested files. You can do that, however, easily with a cron-job ("Delete all files matching `/tmp/*.jpg` older than 1 week").

Comment: _Addendum:_ You can, of course, simply store the whole image in the user's session, but depending on your system's resources this might be a bad idea.